# Proving a billiards bank shot procedure gives equal angles of incidence and reflection

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation, euclidean-geometry, triangles, billiards

One method of making a bank shot in billiards involves imagining two lines, the so called "cross-pocket" and "cross-ball" lines:

[image: Setup #1]

One then projects their point of intersection to the far rail:

[image: Setup #2]

The resulting "bank point" guarantees a successful trajectory with equal angles of incidence and reflection on the far rail. I'm trying to prove that these angles are in fact equal, without using coordinates. Here's a diagram of the scenario with relevant points labeled and line segments drawn:

[image: Setup #3]

Here's the problem: fix point **O** anywhere on the table, and construct all line segments as shown in the diagram above. Prove that **∠OPA** = **∠CPB**. Thanks for the help!

First two pictures are from a helpful article linked [here](https://billiardstation.com/how-to-make-bank-shots-in-your-next-pool-game-super-simple-method/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$
BP:AB=IP:AO
$$
and
$$
AP:AB=IP:BC
$$
one gets (dividing the first equality by the second one):
$$
BP:AP=BC:AO.
$$
Hence triangles $APO$ and $BPC$ are similar and have the same angles.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if there is a way to show this using an angle argument, choosing a few to be x, y, and z, and then filling in remaining angles in terms of these variables.